# How can I simplify this expression in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Range("K4") = FormatPercent(Range("K2") / Range("K3"))
    Range("L4") = FormatPercent(Range("L2") / Range("L3"))
    Range("M4") = FormatPercent(Range("M2") / Range("M3"))
    Range("N4") = FormatPercent(Range("N2") / Range("N3"))
```

I was able to get this to print what I wanted but I'm sure there is a simpler way

I tried
Range("K4:N4") = FormatPercent(Range("K2:N2") / Range("K3:N3"))
but it gave me an error. I'm still new to VBA and was looking for advice. Maybe something with a For loop would work better.

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in Range("K4:N4")`, `cell.Value = FormatPercent(cell.Offset(-2) / cell.Offset(-1))`, `Next cell`.

Answer (score 2):

### Write Percentages

- `FormatPercent` will convert the result to a string.
- If you need the percentages as numbers, you could use one of the following.

```vb
Sub WritePercentages()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Using 'Worksheet.Evaluate' with hard-coded source ranges' addresses
    ' ('K2:N2, K3:N3') to write values.
    With ws.Range("K4:N4")
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Value = ws.Evaluate("K2:N2/K3:N3")
    End With

    ' Using 'Worksheet.Evaluate' with 'Range.Offset' to retrieve
    ' the source ranges' addresses ('$K$2:$N$2, $K$3:$N$3') to write values.
'    With ws.Range("K4:N4")
'        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
'        .Value = ws.Evaluate(.Offset(-2).Address & "/" & .Offset(-1).Address)
'    End With

    ' Using 'Range.Formula' with hard-coded source ranges' addresses
    ' ('K2, K3') to write formulas ('K2/K3', 'L2/L3'...).
'    With ws.Range("K4:N4")
'        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
'        .Formula = "=K2/K3"
'    End With

End Sub
```